# HOW can i use htaccess rewrite rules to replace address?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can i replace address using htaccess? using rewrite rules ...

for example, i want to replace `www.my-site/articles/article1/25/` to this address `www.my-site/my-articles/article1/`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `/articles/article1/25/` a WP page/post?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something along the lines of this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /"PAGENAME"?article=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```